# how to convert an array of geojson which is a string back to geojson object

Tags: angular, typescript

i have the following string, it is composed of two elements. in angular, i receive it as string. i want to convert the entire array/object to object.

```
tr = '[{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[6.692079221624859, 51.132973676729755], [6.692083695415655, 51.13288397493344], [6.692226264428672, 51.132886789666365], [6.6922217909136394, 51.13297649147165], [6.692079221624859, 51.132973676729755]]]}, {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[6.6923643602254, 51.13297930603986], [6.692368833464666, 51.13288960422561], [6.692511402523637, 51.132892418611185], [6.692506929560137, 51.132982120434384], [6.6923643602254, 51.13297930603986]]]}]'
```

how can i convert an array of geojson which is a string back to geojson object

Comment: It's just a google away, https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-convert-js-object-to-json-string.php

Comment: @daysling i want to convert the entire array to be as an array of geojson objects

Comment: Just loop through it and use `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: @daysling it is a string how can i loop through it please

Comment: Convert it to a object and loop through it.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the object as a string, you can use `JSON.parse(value)` to parse it back to the expected array format.

Comment: i want to convert the entire array to geojson object

Comment: An older version of Echarts works when getting the geo .json from a file and converting it with JSON.stringify. Can you try that here?

`http.get(jsonFileUrl).subscribe(geoJson => { ... JSON.stringify(geoJson) ... })`